# Ajax url call with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I a trying to make an ajax call with the URL http://exampleurl.com/site/api/v1/brand/page/1/size/100. I need the page number to change (page/1 in example) based on the response I get from this ajax call. Here is what I currently have

```
    $.when( 
        $.get("http://exampleurl.com/site/api/v1/brand/page/1/size/100", function(result) {
            brands.total = result.totalElements;
            brands.pages = result.totalPages;
            brands.page = result.pageNumber;
            brands.first = result.firstPage;
            brands.last = result.lastPage;
        })
    ).then(function() { ... other data });
```

I would like to $.get("http://exampleurl.com/site/api/v1/brand/page/"+ i +"/size/100"... but I need the loop to be based off of the brands.pages. I have tried putting another ajax call in this get function, however I am unable to set a variable such as brands.data in the second call and retrieve it in the then function. Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
function fetch(page) {
    var url = "http://exampleurl.com/site/api/v1/brand/page/" + page + "/size/100"
    $.get(url, function(result) {
        // do something
        if (page < result.pages) {
            fetch(page + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

What we're doing is fetching the data, processing, then checking if we're done, if not, we call the same function recursively.